# How to Increment an integer in php

Tags: php

I want to Increment an integer in every time +1. Now my code just at first time work after that don't work it does not move to number 2.At first time I can see number 1 in my table but that number do not Increment at second time.

PHP code:

```
<?php
include 'connt.php'; 

$Id = $_POST['Id'];

        
$sql = "UPDATE student SET Posts =? WHERE Id=?" ;       
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$Posts =+1; 
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$Posts,$Id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: `$Posts =+1;` equals `$Posts = 1;` and there's no way it can render `2`. Perhaps you mean `UPDATE student SET Posts = Posts  + 1 WHERE Id=?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$Posts` is never set. Incrementing it will always leave it at 1. You don't need to read values or increment in PHP, you can do it right in your query:

```
<?php
include 'connt.php'; 
$Id = $_POST['Id'];
$sql = "UPDATE student SET Posts = Posts+1 WHERE Id=?" ;       
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$Id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistaken here,

```
$Posts =+1;
```

You probably meant something like this,

```
$Posts++; 
// Or,
$Posts += 1;
```

#### Edit:

Hey You dont even have `$Post` defined in the first place !

Comment: it may be defined in `connt.php`

Comment: then the question in not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$Posts++` to increment your variable.

Answer (score 0):

With this code (if this is all the code), your `$Posts` variable is always 1.

You should first read the number of posts from the database, then increment it by one and then update it to the new value.